# SyntaxError on "self.async" when running python kafka producer

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//producer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I had seen an earlier error identical but I was using `from kafka import KafkaProducer`

My new python script uses `from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer`but I still get the self.async error

Comment: Can you share the code snippet

Comment: Sorry I have since resolved I used kafka-python library instead of just kafka and updated my docker file to use latest python version which resolved the issue

Comment: ***async*** is a reserved word. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#coroutine-function-definition.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You need to install `kafka-python`, not `kafka` package. If `kafka` is installed, then you need to `pip uninstall kafka` and replace with the other

https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1566