# How to resolve SyntaxError in kafka module?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, syntax-error

I updated to kafka-python, now I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
ImportError: cannot import name 'KafkaConsumer' from 'kafka' (unknown location)
```

Previously, when I got the following error, it might have been due to outdated kafka module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
  File "/home/vijay/lehra/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/home/vijay/lehra/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "/home/vijay/lehra/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError on "self.async" when running python kafka producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809459/syntaxerror-on-self-async-when-running-python-kafka-producer)

Comment: what cmd did you use to install it?

Comment: The code of the library seems to be older. It is not compatible with recent Python versions that support the `async` keyword.

Comment: updated code library, now it giver ImportError

Comment: Is your module or another file in your module named kafka.py?

Comment: No. There's only one file "app.py"

Comment: The error indicates that you never uninstalled `kafka` before you installed `kafka-python`

Comment: So, I reinstalled kafka-python and it worked. Why didn't it work before? I have had very limited exposure to Linux.