# Is change kafka to kafka-python in docker container is changing from docker-compose configuration?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Previosly I have error like this [SyntaxError on "self.async" when running python kafka producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809459/syntaxerror-on-self-async-when-running-python-kafka-producer)

Based on the answer, best answer is switch from kafka package to kafka-python package, this is what the detail of my docker-compose configuration, I think to change the docker image because of the docker log still similar

```
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "segmentation"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
```

Do I need to change the docker compose? If yes what to change?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to change the docker configuration? Could you please edit your question to point out what is the current problem?

Comment: The docker log still similar

Comment: It should not require any changes based on your change (kafka package to kafka-python package).

Comment: @JishanShaikh I think so, but without change in docker image, the error still same, because the code is still same

Comment: Our team has been using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/) docker image; if you are willing to try it. Also, if you don't know, Zookeeper is being deprecated in favor of KRaft.

Comment: So Kafka with python3 versions use asynchronous in place of async as in python2. You are getting this error because your python3 is trying to compile Kafka for python2.
First: pip uninstall kafka-python (to remove python2 version of kafka) followed by
Kafka Installation using python3.8 -m pip install kafka-python should do the magic. From: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1566#issuecomment-598655410

Comment: In last comment the quote should make sure you have installed python version same as you have been using in your system.

Comment: https://limascloud.com/2022/01/02/docker-compose-kafka-setup-confluent-cloud/